# My viewport is zoomed?

Tags: android, html, cordova

I wrote an android app using Apache Cordova. The viewport is zoomed by a factor of 2 in . All elements are bigger than they should be. Here's the viewport declaration:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

The viewport is normal when I open the app in the browser. I also have old screenshots taken from the same device where the viewport is normal. I tried clearing the application data, with no luck.

Any idea what could zoom the viewport ?

EDIT:
I created a new cordova project with this html as the only content in www:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <style>
        .view {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            height: 4px;
            background-color:blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="view">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The rendered application still as a scale factor of 2, the blue div as a height of 8px instead of 4px.

[image]

EDIT 2:

I tested on other devices:

- Xpedia X10 has a zoom factor of 1.
- Galaxy S3 has a zoom factor of 2.
- Nexus 5 has a zoom factor of 3.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that devices tries to keep the same aspect on all device, emulating 96 dpi.

> The reference pixel is the visual angle of one pixel on a device with
>   a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm's
>   length. For a nominal arm's length of 28 inches, the visual angle is
>   therefore about 0.0213 degrees. For reading at arm's length, 1px thus
>   corresponds to about 0.26 mm (1/96 inch).

From http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#length-units

> The default ratio depends on the display density.  On a display with
>   density less than 200dpi, the ratio is 1.0.  On displays with density
>   between 200 and 300dpi, the ratio is 1.5.  For displays with density
>   over 300dpi, the ratio is the integer floor(density/150dpi).  Note
>   that the default ratio is true only when the viewport scale equals 1.
>   Otherwise, the relationship between CSS pixels and device pixels
>   depends on the current zoom level.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#A_pixel_is_not_a_pixel